# If someone's memory was wiped, would a Pensieve or Veritaserum work?

Tags: harry-potter

If someone modified your memory, would the contents of your Pensieve disappear? Could you 
use Veritaserum to help you remember the stuff you'd forgotten?

Comment: Probably not Veritaserum. I'm guessing if you already extracted your memory, it will still be there.

Answer (score 3):

Memories that have been extracted appear to have an existence that is separate from the owner's own memories. After the death of Morfin Gaunt, Harry and Dumbledore are still able to view his rememberings in the pensieve. It follows that the **extracted** memories of someone who'd been "*obliviated*" would remain intact, even if their **own** memory was destroyed.

As to whether Veritaserum could be used on someone whose memory had been removed, the answer is probably not. In HP:DH, Harry and crew use a memory charm on a couple of Death Eaters;

> ‘We just need to wipe their memories,’ said Harry. ‘It’s better like
>   that, it’ll throw them off the scent. If we killed them, it’d be
>   obvious we were here.’ ‘You’re the boss,’ said Ron, sounding
>   profoundly relieved. ‘But I’ve never done a Memory Charm.’

If Voldemort and his henchmen could recover memories trivially (through the use of Veritaserum) then removing the Death Eater's memories would be essentially pointless.

Answer (score 0):

There are also documented cases of Memory Charms being broken. When Voldemort was torturing Bertha Jorkins, he inadvertently broke the Memory Charm used on her after she saw Barty Crouch Jr, and Hermione later goes back and restores her parents' memories to normal

Likewise, the answer for the Pensieve is undeniably yes. Dumbledore successfully breaks the Memory Charm used on Morfin Gaunt and collects his memory of meeting Tom Riddle.

But Veritaserum is an interesting case. [Word of God](https://web.archive.org/web/20100305015203/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=105) says that it is not infallible and gifted Occlumens can throw it off entirely. However, Rita Skeeter is able to use Veritaserum to get the completely senile Bathilda Bagshot to accurately recount events nearly a century ago. So it's possible that it can be used to recover lost memories, but there's simply no way to tell.